# Best practice to return error from ASP.NET RESTful webservice in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Here's my service code. I throw an error just like all the best-practice articles suggest - in a form of WebFaultException.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class API
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet()]
    public int MyMethod()
    {
        throw new WebFaultException<string>("TESTERROR", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Now when a send a request to `http://localhost:1389/API.svc/MyMethod` all I get is this JSON object:

> {"ExceptionDetail":null,"ExceptionType":null,"Message":"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.","StackTrace":null}

I tried enabling `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` in my web.config, the message does change a little, but still I don't see my "TESTERROR" anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out you have to add this to the .svc-file: `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"`

And remove the `<behaviors>` section from web.config, leaving only this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="MyAPI"><endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"/></service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that you don't have any sort of return happening, only a response code. So your server is throwing a 500 without any additional info. You can still use this by having the exception details output to a log file.

What I usually do is create a serializable response object that contains a message and any codes that I want returned to the client. Then I catch the exception, build the response object and return that to the client. The client then receives an xml payload that it can read from. So if it's anything other than 200 (OK), then I consider it a fault and display the appropriate message (or details that I included in the xml.

```
<ServiceError>
   <ServerCode>
      500
   </ServerCode>
   <ApplicationCode>
      9100
   </ApplicationCode>
   <Message>
      API key is expired.
   </Message>
</ServiceError>
```

UPDATE:

As far as JSON standard goes, I've never seen an actual document standard. What I HAVE seen is a sort of defacto standard, or rather a trend which is:

```
{
  "status": "success", //or "failed"
  "data": {
    //any app specific payload here
  },
  "message": null //or additional info here (i.e. exception details)
}
```

Comment: I know I can construct anything I want, using HttpContext.Current for example... but what us THE DOCUMENTED way to return errors in a JSON RESTful WCF service?

Comment: I don't think there is an official standard response. But there is a common response (edited my answer)

Comment: yap, thanks for the edit, but I meant - if there's any built-in mechanism in .NET that allows returning this kind of data. Guess not... Ok, I'll wait a couple of days before closing the question thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fall to the same problem and debugged wcf library, ExeptionDetail comes from these lines in WebScriptEnablingBehavior:

> `ExceptionDetail originalFaultDetail = fault.GetDetail<ExceptionDetail>();`

It tries to deserialize error you set to ExceptionDetail type object and fails. 
Use the type ExceptionDetail while creating WebFaultException:

> `throw new WebFaultException<ExceptionDetail>(new ExceptionDetail(new Exception("TESTERROR")), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);`